# leetcode solving single number problem without extra memory

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I've come across a solution to the single number problem from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_6l_ijmcgs which proposes solution below

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        result = 0 
        for i,num in enumerate(nums):
            result ^= num 
        return result
```

but isn't this technically using extra memory since space complexity will be always O(1)?

Comment: Why are you using a enumerate without ever using the index?

Comment: you're right, guess I could have replaced it with an underscore.

Comment: no simply leave it out `for num in nums:` ;)

Comment: All programs use memory, for example a stack frame. Whoever said "without extra memory" presumably meant O(1) memory.

Comment: Extra memory doesn't count use of variables. Extra memory means memory used the program that grows with the size of the input. Here, it's O(1) as it doesn't grow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple code to just check for the non-duplicate element in given array. Solution to [Single Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number/) question in LeetCode.

```
def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    rslt = 0
    for i in nums:
        rslt ^= i
    return rslt
```

This will take almost 280ms(196ms first time).

[image: single_number_solution]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).